# Error while inserting on root in xml using lr_xml_insert

Tags: xml, root, insertion, loadrunner

I am trying to insert xml encoding type on root element but evrytime I am getting this error

```
Action.c(104): Error: attempt to replace root element [class:CLrXmlFuncReplace]
```

I am using this method

```
lr_xml_insert("Xml={XML_Input}",
              "Query=/output",
              "ResultParam=Result1",
              "Postion=before",
              "XmlFragment=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
              LAST);
```

Comment: Please add to the question the content of `XML_input`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: xml content is not imp because the same prob is coming even if I take xml -> <a><b><c></c></b></a>

Comment: Why do you use `lr_xml_insert` and not just prepend the XML definition before the `XML_Input`? I suppose that the method raises the exception when you would be modifying the structure of the document (you wouldn't like to have 2 or more root elements). It's an integrity preservation mechanism and you should have a different approach on this, you are not using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, using lr_xml functions we can't replace the root tag of xml, we can only replace its child tag